# Slow boot: [drm] probing gen 2 caps for device 8086:151 = 261ac83/e

Tags: boot, dmesg, drm

I am using Ubuntu 15.10. I checked `dmesg` and noticed a 30 second gap in the this part:

```
[ 40.947102] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
[ 76.560493] [drm] probing gen 2 caps for device 8086:151 = 261ac83/e
```

I couldn't find any resources in this regard. What to do?

**Update:**

I disabled IPv6. still I see 13 second delay in this line:

```
[   36.515242 <    0.002792>] wlp3s0: associated
[   49.850234 <   13.334992>] [drm] probing gen 2 caps for device 8086:151 = 261ac83/e
[   49.850239 <    0.000005>] [drm] PCIE gen 3 link speeds already enabled
```

Comment: It looks like it's waiting for your ethernet connection to come up.  Does your network support IPv6?

Comment: You mean the 30 sec gap is for the previous line related to IPv6? I don't think I use IPv6, I can go and disable it

Comment: Could be.  Try forcing IPv4.

Comment: I disabled IPv6. Still there is 13 second delay there which shouldn't be normal

Comment: There's a PCIE device that's taking a while to initialize.  From the error it looks like it may be a GPU.  Do you have a Radeon HD 7000 series by any chance?  If so, try installing the proprietary drivers.

Comment: I have Radeon HD 8570M. In settings, I see it is using `X.Org X server` driver. But more than that, I have diver from `fglrx` and `fglrx-update`. Should I go for `fglrx-updates?

Comment: Yes, try that..

Comment: I did. I faced with low graphic issue which wasted hours of my time. Now I am using fglrx. 13 second has reduced to 5. But in total, it didn't reduced the whole boot time. Still I get to my login in 54 second.

Comment: 54 seconds is pretty fast.  I think you may have to put up with that.  My system has an SSD and I never got under about a 45 second boot time.

Comment: 54 seconds is not fast. 16 seconds is. Anyway another question posted today that would interest you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033774/after-upgrading-to-18-04-system-freezes-every-20-40-seconds-for-5-seconds

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've got a GPU driver issue.  Try using the proprietary drivers (looks like you tried and it helped - sort of).

You said you had a 54 second boot time.  That is outstandingly fast.  Even my best Ubuntu system with an SSD had a 45 second boot time at its best.  Be happy, that's a nice time.

Doing more research, however, this looks like it's a (at least partially) [documented bug](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/attachment.cgi?id=82968&action=edit) with an older version of Ubuntu.  I suggest you submit a bug report.

Comment: I checked my `dmesg` today again. The delay beside the same line became 13.86s again. Interestingly, whole boot  takes 56s.

Comment: That's strange.  I'd just leave it as is - this is either a bug or a feature, depending on how you look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Not a real solution - but still worth mentioning in this context: BootChart

> http://www.bootchart.org/

Quoting the project page:

> Bootchart is a tool for performance analysis and visualization of the GNU/Linux boot process. Resource utilization and process information are collected during the boot process and are later rendered in a PNG, SVG or EPS encoded chart.

I used it in the past for debugging boot-issues - it can be really helpful.