# After upgrading to 18.04, system freezes every 20-40 seconds for 5 seconds

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, 18.04, freeze

Appears to be a problem with the video driver. I have a panasonic toughbook with intel HD graphics. I noticed in the syslog, I get a kernel message

[drm] Probing gen 2 caps for device 8086:d910

followed by a bunch of other drm and radeon messages. After every freeze, the system outputs the same info in the syslog.

Not sure where to begin to fix this one.